# Any successful implementations of redux-orm? Having issues

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-orm

I'm trying to implement redux-orm into an application and continue to have issues. I'm basing it off the redux-orm-primer on github my current issue is "schema.register is not a function". this is the code:

```
import ORM from 'redux-orm';
...
export const schema = new ORM();
schema.register(Client, Budget, Category, Subcategory);
```

Has anyone gotten this to work and can you share some insights or code? This is very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

That's not what the `ORM` import looks like as [shown on the redux-orm home page](https://github.com/redux-orm/redux-orm#user-content-register-models-and-generate-an-empty-database-state).

If you're referring to [Tommi's redux-orm-primer](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm-primer) it's not there either.

The correct import is:

```
import { ORM } from 'redux-orm'
```

Comment: Dave thanks for the info, you input has moved me closer.